# Optimize php5-fpm with apache and 8Gb / 6vcore

Tags: apache, optimization, php, pool

I want to optimize the configuration of php5-fpm with apache. On my server I have one site with 4 subdomain all equally important. I configure pool for each subdomain. My server 8Gb of ram and 6vcores. The website will generate a lot of traffic and I would like to optimize at best. On the server running a database mariadb, logwatch, fail2ban, rkhunter, postfix, webmin but nothing more. The server is dedicated to a single site 
At the moment in every pool I put:

```
pm = dynamic 
pm.max_children = 150 
pm.start_servers = 30 
pm.min_spare_servers = 15 
pm.max_spare_servers = 40
```

Can you tell me if it is necessary to add or increase parameter things? 
In addition to this I added an APC cache. If you need more information ask me.
Thanks

Comment: It's a bit overkill from a bird eye view but based on your traffic it might be necessary for what you need. Regardless, it's difficult to give an honest answer to this question as you won't know what settings work best until you watch the load and/or begin to encounter random problems IE: timeouts, etc...